# Azure VM endpoint: mapping public port to a different local port

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I was wondering if it is possible to map a public ip port (e.g. port 80) to a different local/private ip port (e.g. port 81) on a Azure iaas VM. I believe this was doable in the old portal and it is doable via Add-AzureEndpoint (does the Add-AzureEndpoint add the endpoint to the network security group for the VM?) but is it feasible via the new azure portal?

Comment: Agree with 4c74356b41, we can't use NSG to map one port to another port, if you want to do this, you should use Azure Load Balancer NAT rule.

Answer (score 2):

There's a **portproxy** built into `netsh` that can do that for you without additional infrastructure: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731068(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_1

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=81 connectport=80 connectaddress=127.0.0.1
```

If your VM runs Linux just use iptables.

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 81
```

(i'm just winging the syntax for both commands here, don't copy paste but go through the documentation instead.)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use port-forwarding to map a unique external port to an internal port on your VM, use a load balancer and Network Address Translation (NAT) rules. For example, you may want to expose TCP port 8080 externally and have traffic directed to TCP port 80 on a VM. You can learn about creating an Internet-facing load balancer.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-get-started-internet-arm-ps
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/13069704-allow-basic-port-forwarding-in-network-security-gr